# jQuery Regex each match

Tags: jquery, regex, pattern-matching, preg-match

I am using the following jquery code to remove a stylesheet that is already appended to the head of the DOM.

The CSS style sheet will have the following commented lines in the beginning

> /* CSSID=RTP-Executive */

I use the following code to remove the CSS that is already being appended.

```
 if (ele.innerHTML && ele.innerHTML.substring(0, 30).match(/\/\* CSSID=RTP-Executive \*\//)) {
    $(ele).remove();

}
```

This code works fine. 
However if i need to pass in the CSSID dynamically into the  match expression

if i use 
var cssid = RTP-Executive;

> match('/*CSSID=' + cssid + '*/'))

it's not working. (The above is not exact code, I see some slashes are automatically stripped in this display, See the actual code in jsfiddle)

Here is the actual code in jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/jagan2explore/tBrTU/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your string in quotes:

```
var cssid = 'RTP - Executive';
//   here __^    and here __^
```

It seems also that you have a space between `Executive` and `*/`, so the match should be:

```
         match('/\/\* CSSID=' + cssid + ' \*\//'))
//space added here __^        and here __^
```

Or even:

```
match('/\/\*\s*CSSID=' + cssid + '\s*\*\//'))
```

Comment: actually cssid comes from click event, look into the http://jsfiddle.net/jagan2explore/tBrTU/3/ now

Comment: Thanks, I guess those spaces given me the problem.  There is a space in between plus & cssid ( + cssid + ), Those are allowable right?

Comment: @JaganK: spaces arround `+` don't matter.